# Problems compiling with libsoup (gstreamer)

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer, libsoup

I have build the gst-build Gstreamer 1.18 version, after installing libsoup2.4-dev and I can see that the dependency is detected:
|Dependency libsoup-2.4 found: YES 2.62.1 (cached).

Later on, compiling the project that I am developing related with WebRTC I have the following issue. How can I solve it?

```
undefined reference to `soup_websocket_connection_close'
undefined reference to `soup_logger_new'
undefined reference to `soup_websocket_connection_get_state'
undefined reference to `soup_message_new'
undefined reference to `soup_session_websocket_connect_async'
undefined reference to `soup_session_new_with_options'
undefined reference to `soup_session_websocket_connect_finish'
undefined reference to `soup_session_add_feature'
undefined reference to `_SOUP_METHOD_GET'
undefined reference to `soup_websocket_connection_send_text'
undefined reference to `soup_session_feature_get_type
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Are you sure that you added libsoup as a dependency to your project as well? It's not because GStreamer uses libsoup, that your project automaically links to it as well.

Comment: I have the following inlude in my project: #include <libsoup/soup.h>

Comment: Yes, that means you included the libsoup header, but that doesn't mean you actually link to it. Can you update your post to include how you build it?